# Want to make a fragment transition on an toolbar item click

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to transition to the setting fragment when the user clicks the settings button on the toolbar, but I have been trying to make a fragment transition from the onOptionsItemSelected() but I've not been able to do it.
I also a a navigation controller, but I can't find a way to access it from the onOptionsSelected() to make the transition, which I use for every other fragment transition.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        setUpNavigation();
    }


    //bottom bar navigation set up
    public void setUpNavigation(){
        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navHostFragment.getNavController());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){

            case R.id.nav_settings:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Settings Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("debug","fragment: action settings was clicked");

                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new SettingsFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [Android Jetpack's Navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started) then you should not use FragmentMangaer to navigate to fragments.

Find navController as follows -

```
//taking as a global variable here
NavController navController;

public void setUpNavigation(){
    //find NavController
    navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);

    //setting up Toolbar with NavController
    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph()).build();
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
    
    //setting up bottomNavigationView
    bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);
}
```

If you notice `R.id.nav_host_fragment` while finding navController, it will be the same id of host fragment under `activity_main.xml` as follow -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

To tie destination toolbar menu item to destination, you can simply put same id as your fragment in your navGraph

**toolbar_menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    ...

    <item
        android:id="@+id/setting_fragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_details"
        android:title="@string/details" />
</menu>
```

**mobile_navigation.xml (navGraph)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ... >
    ...

    <fragment android:id="@+id/setting_fragment"
         android:label="@string/setting"
         android:name="com.example.android.myapp.SettingFragment" />
</navigation>
```

Notice we given id `setting_fragment` to menu item and setting fragment in navGraph as well.

then you can override `onOptionsItemSelected` as follows -

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)
            || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

And if you not using style as NoActionBar, then there is no need to create toolbar in activity `onCreate()` because android will create a toolbar for you-

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //no need to create a toolbar if style is not NoActionBar
        //Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        setUpNavigation();
    }
```

For more information please follow [Update UI components with NavigationUI](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui)

Happy Coding !